# How to stop Plotly chart rendering process

Tags: plotly.js

I am working with Plotly.js charting library. In order to render a chart I am using Plotly.react(....) command which as all Plotly functions returns a promise. The rendering process might take a time and I need to stop it. Is there a way of doing it?

Thanks